# unmet dependencies when trying to install @ngx-progressbar/core

Tags: angular

I'm trying to practice Angular and wanted to make a progress bar loader using the following Method:

> https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-progressbar

However, when I tried to install: `npm i -S @ngx-progressbar/core`
I had lots of unmet peer dependencies, and I don't know how to solve the problem.

I tried updating the packages using the `npm update` and try it again but still same problem.

and I don't know if it helps or not ( ^^; )but tried running cmd as an administrator and still same problem.

[this is a screenshot of the error that I got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kLR1.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of errors or code but include it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing angular and it's components itself in your project. I would recommend using [angular cli](http://cli.angular.io) to get a running angular application.

Otherwise just add the listed `peerDependencies` as `dependencies` in your `package.json`
 file by installing them: `npm install -S @angular/animations @angular/...`